# Google Search Console reports: "No structured data found on your site" even though the structured data testing tool finds it

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have a website and I am working over its SEO. I have put all required structured data in it as per my knowledge and have also tested it with Google Webmaster's Structured Data Testing Tool and it detects everything fine and all requirements are met.

But back in Webmasters Tools when I go to: Search Appearances > Structured Data it says

> We do not detect any structured data on your site.
>   Structured data helps Google understand the content on your site, which can be used to display rich snippets in search results.

I checked my site with structured data testing tool there are no errors.

Comment: What kind of structure data you're using it?

Answer (score 1):

The structured data testing tool that you used is a real time tool for testing purposes. In other words when you run the request it is done at that time, however this data is not fed back into the Google index. The Search Appearances > Structured Data page extracts relevant data from the index and so won't show anything until the site has been re-crawled and the structured data is processed into the index by Google. This is an automated process that can take anywhere from a few hours to a few weeks depending on the authoritative level of your site (as deemed by Google) and the frequency of content changes (as detected by Google).